# how to check existed username when signUp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to check if the username is already exist or not. this what I've reached but it's not working.

```
 Dim cmdstr As String = "Select count(*) from Registration where username = '" & txtName.Text & "'"
 Dim userExist As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdstr, con)
 Dim temp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
    If (temp = 1) Then
       Response.Write("user name is already Exist!!")
    End If
```

Comment: **SQL INJECTION**, go look it up. What is the error or why "does it not work"?

Comment: it does not give me the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your open for [**SQL-Injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Don't concatenate strings to a sql-query but use [`SqlParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)
2. You haven't opened the connection (i assume)

Here's a full sample:

```
Public Shared Function GetUserCount(userName As String) As Int32
    Const sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration where username = @UserName"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

and use the method in this way:

```
Dim userCount As Int32 = GetUserCount(txtName.Text.Trim())
If userCount > 0
    LblWarning.Text = "User-name already exists!"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. I try it but it gives me this error "
Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

and refers to here "count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)"

Comment: @Hassan: Edited my answer, you should use the `reader.HasRows` property first.

Comment: Charm, Thank you Tim Billion times :)
you saved me ^_^